# Setting up a local Kubernetes installation

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Intel Atom Dual Core with 4 GB RAM left over and want to use it to run docker images. 
What possible solutions are there for such a local installation? I already found MicroK8s which looks promising, yet wondering which other alternatives there are. Is there maybe a complete distribution focused on only running docker containers?

If I would install MicroK8s, I still have to also manage the Ubuntu installation hosting it. Would be nice to have a distribution that only focuses on running docker containers and updates operating system and docker stuff together, so I know it always works fine together.

Comment: you don't need *Kubernetes* to run docker images. *Docker CE* is enough.

Answer (score 2):

- If you can run Docker, run [Docker's Desktop Kubernetes Cluster](https://www.docker.com/products/kubernetes).
- You also can run [`minikube`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/) (on a top of docker, or hypervisor, or virtualbox)
- `kind` - [which is docker in docker k8s cluster.](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/)

Comment: You mean _kubernetes in docker_ I guess? _docker in docker_ sounds confusing.

Comment: well, `kind` is a "docker in the docker", nodes are docker containers. but I am not 100% sure. I listened to a podcast with kind author where this was explained (but didn't touch it myself), my learning setups are `minikube` and kubespray on a top of vagrant/virtualbox .

Answer (score 0):

- This is a lab env for playing with Docker containers on Kubernetes without installing nothing: https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/
- Minikube: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube .
- Docker Swarm: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ is an alternative to kubernetes with less features, but easy to setup. (comparison: https://medium.com/faun/kubernetes-vs-docker-swarm-whos-the-bigger-and-better-53bbe76b9d11)
- Make your own cluster using VirtualBox: https://medium.com/@KevinHoffman/building-a-kubernetes-cluster-in-virtualbox-with-ubuntu-22cd338846dd

Answer (score 0):

[Local-machine Solutions](https://v1-13.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/#local-machine-solutions)

#### Community Supported Tools

- [Minikube](https://v1-13.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/)  is a method for creating a local, single-node Kubernetes cluster for development and testing. Setup is completely automated and doesn’t require a cloud provider account.
- [Kubeadm-dind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubeadm-dind-cluster)  is a multi-node (while minikube is single-node) Kubernetes cluster which only requires a docker daemon. It uses docker-in-docker technique to spawn the Kubernetes cluster.
- [Kubernetes IN Docker](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind)  is a tool for running local Kubernetes clusters using Docker container “nodes”. It is primarily designed for testing Kubernetes 1.11+. You can use it to create multi-node or multi-control-plane Kubernetes clusters.

#### Ecosystem Tools

- [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop)  is an easy-to-install application for your Mac or Windows environment that enables you to start coding and deploying in containers in minutes on a single-node Kubernetes cluster.
- [Minishift](https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/)  installs the community version of the Kubernetes enterprise platform OpenShift for local development & testing. It offers an all-in-one VM (`minishift start`) for Windows, macOS, and Linux. The container start is based on  `oc cluster up`  (Linux only). You can also install  [the included add-ons](https://github.com/minishift/minishift-addons/tree/master/add-ons).
- [MicroK8s](https://microk8s.io/)  provides a single command installation of the latest Kubernetes release on a local machine for development and testing. Setup is quick, fast (~30 sec) and supports many plugins including Istio with a single command.
- [IBM Cloud Private-CE (Community Edition)](https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private)  can use VirtualBox on your machine to deploy Kubernetes to one or more VMs for development and test scenarios. Scales to full multi-node cluster.
- [IBM Cloud Private-CE (Community Edition) on Linux Containers](https://github.com/HSBawa/icp-ce-on-linux-containers)  is a Terraform/Packer/BASH based Infrastructure as Code (IaC) scripts to create a seven node (1 Boot, 1 Master, 1 Management, 1 Proxy and 3 Workers) LXD cluster on Linux Host.
- [Ubuntu on LXD](https://v1-13.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/local/)  supports a nine-instance deployment on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

My very opionated answer: you should use k3s by Rancher Labs https://k3s.io/